# rationalize numerator and find conjugate

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So in our math class today we were going over some problems on how to rationalize the numerator and finding the conjugates. I am completely lost on how you are supposed to go about it I could really use some help with an explanation also. Thank you. I will list two practice problems

First problem: Rationalize the numerator of
$$f(x)=\frac {3-2x}{5x^2}$$

Second problem: Rationalize the numerator of

$$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$$

Comment: There is no square root in the formula you gave for $f(x)$. Are you saying the entire numerator $3-2x$ is in a cube root, so the formula is $f(x)=\frac{{\sqrt[3]{{3 - 2x}}}}{{5{x^2}}}$? Or something else?

Comment: I apologize those are two different problems the first problem is
f(x)=(3-2x)/(5x^2)

Comment: then the second problem is the cubed sqrt with the x in the sqrt

Comment: @RoryDaulton sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: So just what are you supposed to do with $f(x)=\frac {3-2x}{5x^2}$? And is the second problem to rationalize the numerator of $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$?

Comment: yes rationalize the numerator for both @RoryDaulton

Answer (score 0):

In your first question, the numerator $3-2x$ is already rationalized, so it seems that nothing needs to be done.

In your second question, you need to multiply the numerator and denominator of $\frac {\sqrt[3]{x}} 1$ by something to get rid of the root in the numerator (probably adding a root to the denominator). Try multiplying the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$. If you simplify, the root will disappear in the numerator.

Ask if you need more detail. Note that conjugates were not needed in either problem.

Comment: ok how about this. This was the first problem we went over it was 
((sqrt1-4(a+h))-(sqrt1-4a))/h... then the answer ended up being

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{{\sqrt {1 - 4(a + h)} - \sqrt {1 - 4a} }}{h}$? It seems you already have the answer to that. If you have another problem, you should put it in a separate question. And you really should either learn LaTeX (see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) or use a program like MathType (which I sometimes use) to type your questions so they are clear to the rest of us.

Comment: yes I know I need to learn it sorry I didn't finish that question the answer to that ended up being -4/((sqrt1-4(a+h))+(sqrt1-4a))